# Does response body carris call method in python requests ?

Tags: python, python-requests

In python 3.7, I am using "requests" package to try to make an api call in such format:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers, cookies=self.cookies)
or 
response = requests.post(url, headers=self.headers, cookies=self.cookies, data=plan_json)
```

where these are a "get" or "post" call respectively. And in the response body, I can trace the URL data, or the response body value.

But is it possible to also locate the request method from it,  such as the "Get" or "Post", etc ?

Answer (score 1):

A response's request's method is stored at `response.request.method` (as an all-caps strings).

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried and it works. I was coding with PyCharm, somehow, when I edit the code with "response.request", it did not give me this "method" as one of the follow-up options.